# HTML Script Tag be shorten by Tridion

Tags: 2011, templating

We add some customize HTML JavaScript Tag to reference external JS resource, it looks like this:

```
<script src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>
```

But each time Tridion will short it to:

```
<script src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js" />
```

Which is not a correct format. Does anyone know how to stop this action? Thanks!

Best regards,
Chen Qiang

Answer (score 3):

This is a common scenario.  The same question had been asked and answered on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954444/adding-self-closing-tags-in-rtf-field

You can also workaround the problem by simply throwing an html comment or some "syntactic sugar" inside the tags so that it stops being self closing.

Answer (score 3):

Nick's answer is correct, in that if you are using a Rich Text field for this, the data will be processed via XML. A better solution, though, would be to avoid using a Rich Text field. It's quite common to simply use a "code component" (with a plain text field) for HTML head items, and to emit the code on to the page untransformed.